# prove that $\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sum x_1\cdots x_m}{{n\choose m}}} \ge \sqrt[p]{\frac{\sum x_1\cdots x_p}{{n\choose p}}} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be positive real numbers and $1\leq  m < p \leq n, n,m,p\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$ Prove that $\sqrt[m]{\dfrac{\sum x_1\cdots x_m}{{n\choose m}}} \ge \sqrt[p]{\dfrac{\sum x_1\cdots x_p}{{n\choose p}}} $, with equality if and only if $x_i = c\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$, where the sums range over all distinct products of m of the $x_i$'s and all distinct products of $p$ of the $x_i$'s respectively.

It doesn't seem like the AM-GM or Cauchy Schwarz inequalities are useful. Clearly there are ${n\choose m}$ terms in the first sum and ${n\choose p}$ in the second. So by the AM-GM inequality, $\dfrac{\sum x_1\cdots x_m}{{n\choose m}} \ge \sqrt[{n\choose m}]{\prod x_1\cdots x_m}$. It also doesn't seem very useful to take the logarithm of both sides for this problem. I'm also not sure if one can argue the result by finding a convex function.

Comment: How can it be done without knowing which one of $p$ and $m$ ,is bigger or smaller?

Comment: That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality

Comment: It appears you want to prove  
[Maclaurin's inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf#page=3) .

Comment: @Hanno yes. But I haven't been able to find any proofs online.

Comment: @DebjitMullick thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question